# how to make horizontalscrollview scroll-line invisible

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

How to make horizontalscrollview scroll-line invisible?

[image]

Comment: @blahdiblah, march vs september...

Comment: Yes, but the other question got more attention.  The goal is to indicate where the most definitive answer is, not just whichever one came first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apply this property to scrollView in xml file.

```
  android:scrollbars="none"
```

**The following will remove the scrollbar in your scrollview programmatically:**

```
HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)
                                   findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);

horizontalScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: can I make it programmatically?

Comment: it #makesense to add it grammatically...as there are cases where android:scrollbars="none" ignored.

Answer (score 0):

use this property for scroll view

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

Comment: can I make it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it programmatically:

```
    HorizontalScrollView myView = (HorizontalScrollView)
                                   findViewById(R.id.myHorizontalScrollView);
    myView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

But I don't recommend you to do it programmatically. Try to move all code into separate layouts, all attributes into separate styles